# Can we export Views via 'exp' command in Unix

Tags: oracle, unix

Can we use Export command to export the Views dumps in Unix. It is working when I am mentioning table names in the command but it is failing for Views.

It is failing for below Views: `CUSTOMER_SITES` and `JOB_CONFIGS`.

Error I am getting:

> EXP-00011: NM.CUSTOMER_SITES does not exist
>
> $ORACLE_HOME/bin/exp $ORACLE_USER/$ORACLE_PW@$DB_TNS_NAME file=$filename.dmp log=$filename.log tables=managed_devices,customers,networks,device_types,polling_classes,S_BFG_NETWORK_NODES,LOG_CLASSES,EIN,CLIENT_GROUPS,DEVICE_LOGS,CUSTOMER_SITES,JOB_CONFIGS  buffer=20480000 CONSTRAINTS=n GRANTS=n INDEXES=n TRIGGERS=n STATISTICS=NONE

Comment: Why are you still using the legacy `exp` tool, instead of the data pump `expdp`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use syntax as:

```
VIEWS_AS_TABLES=NM.CUSTOMER_SITES
```

to be able to export view. And your command will be something like:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/exp $ORACLE_USER/$ORACLE_PW@$DB_TNS_NAME file=$filename.dmp log=$filename.log tables=managed_devices,customers,networks,device_types,polling_classes,S_BFG_NETWORK_NODES,LOG_CLASSES,EIN,CLIENT_GROUPS,DEVICE_LOGS,CUSTOMER_SITES,JOB_CONFIGS buffer=20480000 CONSTRAINTS=n GRANTS=n INDEXES=n TRIGGERS=n STATISTICS=NONE VIEWS_AS_TABLES=CUSTOMER_SITES,JOB_CONFIGS
```

Comment: Can I use tables as well with this or do I need to provide only Views?   

VIEWS_AS_TABLES= tables_name

Comment: @Himmy, you can combine them, check my edited answer

Comment: Tried but getting below error:LRM-00101: unknown parameter name 'views_as_tables'

Comment: LRM-00101: unknown parameter name 'views_as_tables'

Comment: @Himmy, in such case will be best to use `expdp`

Comment: I am using 11g, is it a feature of 12c?

Comment: as with expdp still we are getting error as views_as_tables parameter does not exist

Comment: @Himmy, in case of `expdp` you do not need to add views_as_tables

Comment: so are you saying that I can mention my view names in the same section where I am giving my table names?

Comment: @Himmy - you might want [the `include` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL853). The `views_as_tables` parameter [was added in 12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-F4EE2A42-3986-4597-9088-A506173ABABF.htm#SUTIL4298). Both only apply to `expdp`, not `exp`.

Comment: Ok that means I cannot implement this in 11g as Views can be exported from 12c Onwards. Please correct me If I my understanding is wrong. Also, I have one more question, If I export table and that table is having BLOB field So, while exporting that table I am getting an error 'Device Size is full'. Is there any way I can rid out from this problem?

Comment: `include` is supported in 11g (I linked to the docs for that version) so you can export view metadata using that AFAIK. The device error sounds like you're just running out of space on the target directory.